# How to fix this error while executing a program

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\skandregula\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe 

C:/Users/skandregula/Desktop/TestFiles2/testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/skandregula/Desktop/TestFiles2/testing.py", line 30, in <module>
    with open(in_dir + f, 'r') as tmp_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:/Users/skandregula/Desktop/TestFiles2/history.log.3.3C'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

that is the error i am running right now...How to fix this?

Comment: Your error does not depend on whether you are using pycharm or not

Comment: as @sc_ says it isnt probably a pycharm error, but even if it is, i guess it is about selected working directory. to test it you can use full path

Comment: Please, include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sometimes this will help you figure out the issue by yourself, and surely helps the community. Also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your code looks like, I'm assuming somewhere in your code you're referencing a file or folder named 'history.log.3.3C' as the error suggests, and that it cannot find it in your directory given. My best advice is make sure the directory is correct?

Hard to tell without seeing what you're trying to do. Maybe posting a snippet of your code would help.